# Train/Validation/Test split in Zero-Shot learning?

Tags: zero-shot-learning

Is it recommended to do test/validation epochs in zero shot learning tasks? how can one split the unseen and seen classes in that case?

Can the validation set be a mixture of the two, under the assumption that we do not update the weights in validation steps?

If so, how can it help? would it be OK to use such thing to (for instance) observe overfitting and to stop the training process at a different phase?